# Good FTP control?

Tags: vb.net, ftp-client

I need to find a good control for VB.Net to upload big files to an FTP server:

- Can upload files up to 10GB
- Uses passive mode
- Provides feedback during upload, to make sure it's going OK
- Can cancel and resume
- Up to two concurrent connections

I read about WebClient + NetworkCredential, but it doesn't seem to provide progress infos. There are also the FTPWebRequest/FTPWebResponse classes from WebRequest/WebResponse, as well as WebClient.UploadFileAsync.

Which free/affordable solution would you recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should expect the following to be provided by every FTP client classes/controls, as they are supported by FTP the protocol.

- Can upload files up to 10GB
- Uses passive mode
- Can cancel and resume

The following requires you to make good use of the classes/controls, for example, use two client classes/controls at the same time.

- Up to two concurrent connections

RemObjects has a free pack called Internet Pack, where you can find a class called FtpClient,

http://www.remobjects.com/ip.aspx

http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/FtpClient_Class

It supports all FTP features above, and it provides upload progress too, via events. You can read its documentation or simply write a small program to test it out.

To support multiple connections to the same FTP server, you can create multiple instances of this class.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What useful features does RemObjects provide that aren't available in the .Net framework?

Comment: Just edited the answer. RemObjects designs a better API (many FTP details have been hidden/encapsulated for you) compared to what Microsoft offers in .NET BCL.

Comment: I have to say your searching skill is not good enough, as they have the source code published here, http://code.remobjects.com/p/internetpack/source/tree/HEAD/Source Try to learn how to use a search engine properly. Thanks.